# Looking for a simple method to adjust positions of grid points

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm looking for a good method to shift grid points around in a numerical problem that I am solving (gradient descent).  I was hoping someone knew of a good resource that discussed simple methods to shift the positions of grid points to make a resulting integration more accurate.  I don't think I need a fancy method, just something for one dimension.  I'm having more trouble finding a simple explanation than I thought I would.

Something like shifting the points towards larger values of the function I'm integrating would be fine, but I don't want to guess on how to write the cost function for shifting the grid points and want to do something established instead of making a new method.

Comment: In one dimension the aim would be to have a uniform local error (density). Do you have a method to estimate the local error?

Comment: Between iterations I can look at the difference, but it's a gradient descent and I don't know what the answer is ahead of time.  Other than looking at the convergence of the resulting integral, I'm not sure what else to look at in this regard.

Comment: You can refine the grid by adding the midpoints of the intervals. Extend the existing solution via interpolation using all available data and apply a solver step. How much this moves from the interpolated solution gives you a localized error estimate. Slight imbalances can be corrected by shifting the nodes of the existing grid, large local errors need to be compensated by adding the midpoints. (This is just an ad-hoc idea, there might be less costly error estimates and refinement strategies in the literature on adaptive grids.)

Comment: Thank you for this, I did find a few of these. I know that for partial differential equations, one can automatically shift the grid positions, but I was hoping that something like that could apply here.  Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to use Gauss-Legendre quadrature] (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).  Suitably scaled your grid points are the points defined by the given order of integrator. This has a good reputation for accuracy and simplicity.